# Detecting if the code read the specified input file

Tags: linux, file, io

I am writing some automated tests for testing code and providing feedback to the programmer.

One of the requirements is to detect if the code has successfully read the specified input file. If not - we need to provide feedback to the user accordingly. One way to detect this was `atime` timestamp, but since our server drive is mounted with `relatime` option - we are not getting `atime` updates for every file read. Changing this option to record every `atime` is not feasible as it slows down our I/O operations significantly.

Is there any other alternative that we can use to detect if the given code indeed reads the specified input file?

Comment: Even with full `atime` support, how do you differentiate between code reading the whole file and reading only a part of it? Do you really need to check that? Maybe verify code output instead (which would match if it read and processed the file)?

Comment: I agree with Sergio: touching a file doesn't mean that it was read successfully. If you want to be really "sure"; those programs have to "send" some sort of indication back.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - We are already checking for output that would be generated only after processing the input, but we need to detect if the programmer has correctly read the file (partial won't be useful for creating output, so we are covered here). Often we have seen them making errors with paths (blame it on `C:` :P), we want to detect that and provide relevant feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wild idea: intercept read call at some point. One of possible approaches goes more or less like this:

1. The program makes all its reading through an abstraction. For example, `MyFileUtils.read(filename)` (custom) instead of `File.read(filename)` (stdlib).
2. During normal operation, `MyFileUtils` simply delegates the work to `File` (or whatever system built-in libraries/calls you use).
3. But under test, `MyFileUtils` is replaced with a special test version which, along with the delegation, also reports usage to the framework.

Note that in some environments/languages it might be possible to inject code into `File` directly and the abstraction will not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sergio: touching a file doesn't mean that it was read successfully. If you want to be really "sure"; those programs have to "send" some sort of indication back. And of course, there are many options to get that.

A pragmatic way could be: assuming that those programs under test create log files; your "test monitor" could check that the log files contain fixed entries such as "reading xyz PASSED" or something alike.

If your "code under test" doesn't create log files; maybe: consider changing that.

Comment: Perhaps, one could intercept system calls or something. To really verify that the program opened and read the file. Don't know the requirements, but this looks like total overkill. :)

Comment: It depends :  if the log files are already there probably not at all